# Uso do delete em um ponteiro de uma classe abstrata

Tags: c++, ponteiro, alocação, classes-abstratas, destrutor

Lendo o livro *A tour of C++*, numa seção sobre vazamento de memória, quando me deparei com 3 afirmações em relação ao código abaixo:

1. A implementação de `Smiley` pode falhar ao deletar o ponteiro para `mouth`.
2. A tentativa de deletar o ponteiro retornado de `read_shape()` pode falhar.
3. Uma variável do tipo `Shape*` pode falhar ao tentar deletar o objeto para que aponta.

Texto original:

> Experienced programmers will have noticed that I left open three opportunities for mistakes:
> • The implementer of Smiley may fail to delete the pointer to mouth.
> • A user of read_shape() might fail to delete the pointer returned.
> • The owner of a container of Shape pointers might fail to delete the objects pointed to.

**O CÓDIGO ABAIXO NÃO COMPILA, É APENAS UMA REPRESENTAÇÃO DO LIVRO PARA ENTENDER O PROBLEMA.**

```cpp
class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual ~Shape() {}
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
    public:
        Circle(Point _center, int _rad) : center { _center }, rad { _rad }
        {}

    private:
        Point center;
        int rad;
};

class Smiley : public Circle
{
    public:
        Smiley(Point center, int rad) : Circle { center, rad }, mouth { nullptr }
        {}

        ~Smiley()
        {
            delete mouth; // Referencia da primeira afirmação.
            for (auto eye : eyes)
                delete eye;
        }

        void set_mouth(Shape* _mouth)
        {
            mouth = _mouth;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Shape*> eyes;
        Shape* mouth;

};

Shape* read_shape(std::istream& is)
{
    //Read kind_of_shape

    switch (kind_of_shape)
    {
        case Circle:
            //Read p, r.
            return new Circle { p, r };
            break;

        case Triangle:
            //Read p1, p2, p3.
            return new Triangle { p1, p2, p3 };
            break;

        case Smiley:
            //Read {Point, int} int p, r.
            Smiley∗ ps = new Smiley{p,r};
            return ps;
            break;
    }
}
```

Percebi que o problema da implementação estava então no `Shape*`, ou seja, um ponteiro para uma classe abstrata, mas não entendi qual o problema.
O texto ainda descreve:

> Ponteiros para objetos alocados na `free store`¹ são perigosos: um ‘‘plain old pointer’’² não deveria ser usado para representar uma propriedade.

Texto original:

> ... pointers to objects allocated on the free store is dangerous: a ‘‘plain old pointer’’ should not be used to represent ownership.

A dúvida que ficou é: **Porque o comando `delete` em uma varíavel do tipo `Shape*` talvez falhe?**  .

---

[1][2] Não conheço uma tradução adequada.

---

*A solução para este problema apresentada pelo texto é usando `std::unique_ptr<Shape>()` no lugar de `Shape*`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Percebi que o problema da implementação estava então no Shape*, ou seja, um ponteiro para uma classe abstrata, mas não entendi qual o problema

O problema não está em `Shape` nem no fato dela ser abstrata.
Problemas aparecem em `read_shape()` porque ela retorna um ponteiro, e em `Smiley` porque uma das propriedades é um ponteiro.

São pontas soltas e estão fora do controle. É esse o tema: "Avoiding Resource Leaks" em 4.5.3: evitar vazamentos.

#### Caso 1

Uma das propriedades de `Smiley` é um ponteiro para `mouth`, inicializado com `nullptr` no construtor padrão. Isso é um risco.

> A dúvida que ficou é: Porque o comando delete em uma varíavel do tipo Shape* talvez falhe?

Não foi isso que o prof. Stroustrup escreveu. Ele escreveu:

> "The implementer of `Smiley` may fail to delete the pointer to `mouth`"

algo como "*o implementador de `Smiley` pode falhar em apagar o ponteiro para `mouth`*". E se falhar aí já era. O autor não falava da possibilidade do comando `delete` falhar.

#### Caso 2

```
Shape* read_shape(std::istream& is)
```

Quem chamar isso recebe um `Shape*` **e uma responsabilidade**. É mais uma ponta solta --- *loose-end* --- e se o cara não liberar ja era também.

#### Caso 3

```
class Smiley : public Circle
{
    public:
        Smiley(Point center, int rad) : Circle { center, rad }, mouth { nullptr }
        {}

        ~Smiley()
        {
            delete mouth; // Referencia da primeira afirmação.
            for (auto eye : eyes)
                delete eye;
        }

        void set_mouth(Shape* _mouth)
        {
            mouth = _mouth;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Shape*> eyes;
        Shape* mouth;

};
```

Veja o código do destrutor de `Smyley` acima: primeiro resolve o caso 1 e depois o caso 3.

Um `Smiley` tipo aranha vai ter 8 olhos. E se ele apagar só 7?

```
    private:
        std::vector<Shape*> eyes; // usually two eyes
        Shape* mouth;
```

Esse é o problema. Quem escreveu `Shape` ou `Circle` não tem culpa. `Shape` é abstrata e não tem problema, até alguém derivar desse modo.

De todo modo, responsabilidade não era pra ser um problema. É a vida.
Mas a idéia nesse ponto é introduzir `unique_ptr<>` como uma solução de não deixar essas coisas em aberto.

E reforçar o fato de que numa hierarquia de derivação de classes os construtores são chamados "de fora para dentro" e os destrutores ao contrário. Assim ao criar `Smiley` primeiro cria `Shape` depois `Circle` depois `Smiley`. Mas ao destruir `Smiley` a ordem é inversa.

Comment: Então no primeiro caso, eu fiz a confusão pois não soube traduzir o texto da maneira correta né?

Comment: E porque "o implementador de Smiley pode falhar em apagar o ponteiro para mouth" se o destrutor de Smiley invoca delete mouth? O destructor de Smiley não deveria ser chamado assim que saísse do escopo?

Comment: "Veja o código do destrutor de Shape: primeiro resolve o caso 1 e depois o caso 3." O destrutor de Shape está vazio, como ele resolve algo?

Comment: Esse é o ponto: `Shape` não criou nenhum problema. `Smiley` introduziu uma vulnerabilidade. Não é o fim do mundo. E por isso os destrutores começam a ser invocados pela classe mais interna.  E o autor fala em hipóteses. "Se" o implementador falhar. Nesse exemplo não falhou. E eu escrevi errado: me referia ao destrutor de `Smiley` que faz o esperado e na ordem certa. Desculpe. Vou corrigir